# Codeigniter passing parameter in get from view results in 404 error

Tags: php, url-rewriting, url-routing, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to pass parameter to my function like :

```
<a href="mydomain.com/admin/controller/functionxyz/parameter"> edit</a>
```

in my controller

```
function  functionxyz($parameter=null){}
```

this results in 404 error if I'm passing without any parameters it reaches the function.
I've tried routing and uri segment none is working.

Update:
When I'm using get in url it works perfectly fine like :

```
<a href="mydomain.com/admin/controller/functionxyz?parameter=abc"> edit</a>
```

I land 404 page only if i'm trying to pass in function as parameter.

Update:
So My route is something like this:

```
$route['cmcp/company/edit'] = 'cmcp/company/edit';
$route['cmcp/company/edit/(:any)'] = 'cmcp/company/edit/$1';
```

where cmcp is my admin controller that extends a controller named company and has function edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 2 entries to your router. One without any params and one with param supplied like this:

```
$route['admin/controller/functionxyz'] = 'admin/controller/functionxyz';
// for only 1 param
$route['admin/controller/functionxyz/(:any)'] = 'admin/controller/functionxyz/$1';
// for multiple params
$route['admin/controller/functionxyz/(.+)'] = 'admin/controller/functionxyz/$1';
```

Comment: Thanks but i tried this already and it still lands on 404 page.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file and if yes could you post your content?

Comment: Thank Mikey, i tried same but its 404 page. yes, I have htaccess also .I'll share my code.

Answer (score 0):

Given a controller named `Home` in the directory */application/controllers/admin/* which has the method `public function xyz($param = null) ...` the best approach is to use remapping of the URI. But we have to **actually remap** the URI's. With that in mind, these routes should work. (Note that the `$route` key and value really do differ.)

```
$route['home'] = 'admin/home/xyz';
$route['home/(.+)'] = 'admin/home/xyz/$1';
```

So the link would be like so

```
<a href="example.com/home/parameter"> edit</a>
```

IMO, the above is a totally unnecessary complication. Unless you're a total control freak or have hundreds of controllers there is seldom a valid reason to break CI's `/class/function/id/` URI pattern. The only outcome from putting controllers in subfolders is to make life more complicated.

Comment: So,if my controller needs two functions one for edit and other for delete actions or I  want to pass more parameters,what will  happen in that case? and what about my index function?

Comment: If you would like to create a simple URL for each controller/function then you will need to create routes for each combo. The regex `(.+)` will append all found URI segments (i.e. more parameters) to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to activate helper 'url' and use base_url function ?

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('controller/functionxyz/').'parameter' ?>"> edit</a>
```

Comment: Actually I've even tried it without anchor, it seems something is wrong with my settings,maybe.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<a href="mydomain.com/admin/controller/functionxyz/parameter"> edit</a>
```

with

```
<?php echo anchor('controller/functionxyz/parameter','edit'); ?>
```

See what happens and give me feedback.
According to me there is no need to write routing rules for this. As someone said it feels like a control freak.
Instead try to give some default value to parameter and do something accordingly.

Example :

```
function  functionxyz($parameter="notgiven"){
        if ($parameter == "notgiven"){
            //do something
        }else{
            //do what you want with the parameter
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its not control freak, I used it as an example my point is only that I'm landing on 404 page. When I'm trying to send parameters in url like this but when i send it as get it works perfectly fine. I tried your method it still 404

Comment: first thing that comes to mind is have you set the base url correctly in config file? And also have you correctly removed index.php ?

Comment: if you are generating parameter dynamically try <?php echo anchor('controller/functionxyz/'.$parameter,'edit'); ?>

Comment: index.php is already removed ,and the base url is correct as I see it working in fetching the data and so on.. My parameters are dynamic but when I use this method its still 404. as I mentioned if i pass parameters in get its working fine.

Comment: $route['cmcp/company/edit'] = 'cmcp/company/edit';
$route['cmcp/company/edit/(:any)'] = 'cmcp/company/edit/$1';

Comment: Remove both the route records. And just echo anchor as I said earlier. It should work perfectly. As I see you have already removed index.php and have set your base url correctly.

Comment: Ok i removed the routes, added the same code like ```<?php echo anchor('cmcp/company/edit/'.$row['id'],'edit'); ?> ``` it creates the anchor but again its 404

Comment: Is there anything I have to do with config to make the url work?

Comment: Please share if you have a GitHub page for this. It's very difficult to understand. It might just be some PHP issue.